# mysql - Duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, store

Overview:

- have 2 tables
- joining them with the entry_id which is in both tables (this works)
- storing those results in tableStore
- then taking those values in tableStore sorting it in descending order by field_id_13

CODE:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT *  
            FROM exp_channel_data 
            LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles 
            ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
            WHERE field_id_13 > '1' 
            ORDER BY field_id_13 
            ASC LIMIT 6
    ) AS tableStore) 
AS tableStore 
ORDER BY field_id_13 DESC
```

ERROR:
 - "Duplicate column name 'entry_id'"

Question:
 - how do i fix the above code so the error doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

I will do away with all that extraneous nesting and instead write this more simply as:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT ecd.entry_id,
                       ecd.field_id_13,
                       ecd.field_id_11,
                       ect.title
                FROM exp_channel_data ecd
                LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles ect
                ON ecd.entry_id = ect.entry_id 
                WHERE ecd.field_id_13 > '1'
                ORDER BY ecd.field_id_13 ASC
                LIMIT 6
              )
ORDER BY field_id_13 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as duplicate column stated one of the select statements need to be defined more.

```
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT exp_channel_data.entry_id, exp_channel_data.field_id_13, exp_channel_data.field_id_11, exp_channel_titles.title  
        FROM exp_channel_data 
        LEFT JOIN exp_channel_titles 
        ON exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id 
        WHERE field_id_13 > '1' 
        ORDER BY field_id_13 
        ASC LIMIT 6
    ) AS tableStore) 
AS tableStore ORDER BY field_id_13 DESC
```